# HTTPWebRequest Cookie different behaviour

Tags: c#, http, cookies

I'm developing an application that needs to login into a website, www.example.com, using the class HTTPWebRequest and a CookieJar to handle Cookies.

The problem I have is that on some computers, the procedure works just fine, but on some others ( with a 1-1 ratio) it doesn't, with no SO/IE version pattern whatsoever.

I've tried logging every single GET and POST request, and here is the problem:

**WORKING REQUEST**

> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0
>
> Referer: http://account.example.com/login
>
> Host: main.example.com
>
> Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=gw5i1u55h5dz1uuydwhvu2er; ISBets_CurrentCulture=1; ISBetsForm=AAAA; SESSb3ef0b97a175642ae0744781875xxxxx=00000157671f81d4ea9f3589198768d4; authcache=59c1bd; drupal_user=foo; drupal_uid=543; isib_name=foo+bar

**NOT WORKING REQUEST**

> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0
>
> Referer: http://account.example.com/login
>
> Host: main.example.com
>
> Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=gw5i1u55h5dz1uuydwhvu2er; ISBets_CurrentCulture=1; ISBetsForm=AAAA;

The application is the same, and I use an HTTPWebRequest with an empty cookiejar every new restart of the program, and those are the request headers of the **first** POST request of the application: so, my question is, why are those 2 different? Shouldn't a cookiejar be empty the first time you use it? so, where the extra cookies come from?

After some other tests, I'm starting to doubt that the crossdomain "trick"  is the whole problem, but again, is it possible that an option in IE makes this Set-Cookie an error:

> Set-Cookie: SESSb3ef0b97a175642ae0744781875xxxxx=00000157671f81d4ea9f3589198768d4; expires=Mon, 18-Mar-2013 23:48:14 GMT; path=/; domain=.example.com;
>   HttpOnly,authcache=59c1bd; expires=Mon, 18-Mar-2013 23:48:14 GMT; path=/; domain=.example.com,
>   drupal_user=foo; expires=Mon, 18-Mar-2013 23:48:14 GMT; path=/; domain=.example.com,
>   drupal_uid=543; expires=Mon, 18-Mar-2013 23:48:14 GMT; path=/; domain=.example.com,
>   isib_name=foo+bar; expires=Mon, 18-Mar-2013 23:48:14 GMT; path=/; domain=.example.com